# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I created an app to parse a XML file using SAXParser and the code is below.

Below is the code of my main activity.

```
public class XMLAppActivity extends Activity{
 ArrayList<Question> questionList = new ArrayList<Question>();          
 TextView tvXmlReader;
 InputSource xmlSource;
 InputStream xmlIs;
 String xmlFile;


  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      tvXmlReader=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_xml);

      try 
        {
          xmlIs= getAssets().open("surveyquestions.xml");
          xmlFile = convertStreamToString(xmlIs);
        } 
        catch (IOException e1)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } 

     xmlSource=  new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlFile));
      tvXmlReader.setText(parseXML().toString());
  }

 private String parseXML() {

        try {


            /** Handling XML */
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

            QuestionXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new QuestionXMLHandler();
            xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);

            xr.parse(xmlSource);

            questionList= myXMLHandler.getQuestionList();
            return "Success";

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
          return "Failure due to " + e.toString();
        }
   }

 public  String convertStreamToString(InputStream is)
            throws IOException {
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();

            char[] buffer = new char[2048];
            try {
                Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
                int n;
                while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
                }
            } finally {
                is.close();
            }
            String text = writer.toString();
            return text;
    }
}
```

This is the code for my XMLhandler.

```
public class QuestionXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

private ArrayList<Question> questionL= new ArrayList<Question>();
Question cQuestion;
Boolean cElement = false;
String cValue = "";


public ArrayList<Question> getQuestionList() {
    return questionL;
}


@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    cElement = true;
    cValue = "";

    // if current element is Question , create new question
    // clear tmpValue on start of element

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Question")) {
        cQuestion = new Question();
        cQuestion.setQuestionId(attributes.getValue("id"));
        cQuestion.setQuestionName(attributes.getValue("name"));
        cQuestion.setQuestionType(attributes.getValue("type"));
        cQuestion.setQuestionIsRequired(Boolean.parseBoolean(attributes.getValue("isRequired")));
    }


}


@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
      if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Question")) {
          questionL.add(cQuestion);
        }
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("QuestionText")) {
            cQuestion.setQuestionText(cValue);
        }

        if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Answer")){
            cQuestion.getAnswers().add(cValue);
        }

}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    cValue = new String(ch,start,length);
}
}
```

And This is my Question class.

```
public class Question 
{
private String qId;
private String qName;
private String qType;
private String qText;
private Boolean isRequired;
private String qSurveyId;
private List<String> answers;

public Question()
{
    qId="";
    qName="";
    qType="";
    qText="";
    isRequired=false;
    qSurveyId="";

}
 //getters and setter methods
}
```

But I m getting an error of:

```
06-27 14:44:36.148: W/System.err(591): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-27 14:44:36.187: W/System.err(591):  at com.optimus.mobile.xml.QuestionXMLHandler.endElement(QuestionXMLHandler.java:52)
06-27 14:44:36.187: W/System.err(591):  at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.endElement(ExpatParser.java:160)
06-27 14:44:36.187: W/System.err(591):  at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.append(Native Method)
06-27 14:44:36.187: W/System.err(591):  at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:505)
06-27 14:44:36.197: W/System.err(591):  at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:492)
06-27 14:44:36.197: W/System.err(591):  at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:308)
06-27 14:44:36.197: W/System.err(591):  at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:264)
06-27 14:44:36.197: W/System.err(591):  at com.optimus.mobile.xml.XMLAppActivity.parseXML(XMLAppActivity.java:68)
06-27 14:44:36.197: W/System.err(591):  at com.optimus.mobile.xml.XMLAppActivity.onCreate(XMLAppActivity.java:52)
06-27 14:44:36.197: W/System.err(591):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-27 14:44:36.197: W/System.err(591):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
06-27 14:44:36.197: W/System.err(591):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-27 14:44:36.197: W/System.err(591):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-27 14:44:36.197: W/System.err(591):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-27 14:44:36.197: W/System.err(591):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-27 14:44:36.207: W/System.err(591):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-27 14:44:36.207: W/System.err(591):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-27 14:44:36.207: W/System.err(591):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 14:44:36.207: W/System.err(591):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-27 14:44:36.207: W/System.err(591):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-27 14:44:36.207: W/System.err(591):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-27 14:44:36.207: W/System.err(591):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You should have put less code and more logs!!

Comment: Where is the error coming from? What caused it?

Comment: put full logcat,and logcat have class name and line no. also see [this](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/why-nullpointerexception-occures-in.html)

Comment: I have added my full logcat now

Comment: Thanks guys for all your help !! 
I spotted my mistake !! it was in the End Element method of my XML handler class.

basically some problem in the below line.


     if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Answer"))
    {
            cQuestion.getAnswers().add(cValue);
    }

So I removed it.
But this gives me another problem and that is In my question class I have a List of Answers and as you can see my xml under the Answers tag , I have to add all these answers in my class so how can i achieve it, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I spotted my mistake !! it was in the End Element method of my XML
>   handler class. basically some problem in the below line.
>   if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Answer")) {
>   cQuestion.getAnswers().add(cValue); }

worked for me

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
xmlIs= this.getResources().getAssets().open("surveyquestions.xml");
```

instead of

```
xmlIs= getAssets().open("surveyquestions.xml");
```

Comment: I m able to read the XML file , that I have tested , the problem is appearing when I try to parse the file using SAX parser

Comment: I have seen @Dheeresh  Answer, but still running into the same issue

Comment: I have posted my full logt cat now

Comment: @AdityaPratap : which is Line number QuestionXMLHandler.java:52 in your code?

Comment: Imran Khan :- thnx buddy fr ur help , QuestionXMLHandler.java:52 basically it is the end element method of my handler class   if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Answer")){
          cQuestion.getAnswers().add(cValue);
         }. I commented that part and program is now working fine. But that leads me to another problem . as you can see in my XMl inside question tag I have answers tag and inside answers tag I have multiple answers , so what i wanted to do was that add all these answers to my Question class answers list member. but somehow the logic fails , can u suggest any alternative to do that

Comment: :- no problem is still open , basically i m not able to add all answers in my list answer member of question class

Answer (score 0):

I think "`questionL`" not initialized in your code.........

used in below code.......

```
 @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
          if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Question")) {
              questionL.add(cQuestion);
            }
            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("QuestionText")) {
                cQuestion.setQuestionText(cValue);
            }

            if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Answer")){
                cQuestion.getAnswers().add(cValue);
            }

    }
```

Comment: I have initialized it and updated the code above , but still its giving the same error

Comment: I have added my full log cat!!

Comment: can you try with h this private ArrayList<Question> questionL= new ArrayList<Question>();
Question cQuestion = new cQuestion(); for a test in your code........

Comment: @Dheerash : i spotted the problem , thnx, it was in the End Element method of my handler class, on this line if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Answer")){
            cQuestion.getAnswers().add(cValue);
        }  , as u can see from above

Comment: but the problem still persists , I m not able to add all my answers to my list<answer> member of the question class\

Comment: gr8.......... want to confirm the problem is with cQuestion as I said in my last comment to test or any other place?

Comment: I just traced the LogCat and found the error, by d way dheeresh the problem was with cQuestion only , so thnx buddy, u saved me